# Реклама. Размещение. Стоимость

Tags: поддержка, реклама

Сколько стоит размещение рекламы у вас на сайте?

Comment: https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertise

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратитесь к сайту [Stack Overflow Business](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/), ссылка на который находится в подвале сайта. С большой вероятностью, вам необходимо найти нужный вам инструмент, например, [раздел Ads, отвечающий за рекламу](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertise), и запросить стоимость, которая, на сколько я понимаю, будет рассчитана индивидуально для вас.

Answer (score 0):

Если ваш бюджет больше $5000 тысяч, то вам сюда:

https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertise

Если нет, то вот форма для заказы рекламы с расчётом стоимости:

https://www.selfserve-stackexchange.com/ ([ссылка на неё нашлась здесь](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertise/talk-to-an-expert))

Comment: Этот сайт разве как-то связан с официальным сайтом stackexchange? Домен похожий, но похоже, что это какая-то отдельная контора ('third-party'), а значит, что этот ответ можно расценивать как спам, либо недобросовестную рекламу.

Comment: @AK это, судя по всему, официальный калькулятор, просто старый, и без прямой ссылки - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243364/what-sites-have-advertisements-enabled#comment817066_243521

Comment: Это очень официальный калькулятор и не похоже чтобы старый. Сначала [идём сюда](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertise), [потом сюда](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertise/talk-to-an-expert) и находим ссылку на этот калькулятор рядом со словами "The range for a self-serve campaign is $500-$4,999.